# Code works in Chrome and IE11 but not IE9

Tags: html, css

My pages work fine in Chrome and IE11, but not IE9. Am I missing something. Below is what I have. In Chrome and IE11 this centers my buttons to the middle of the page, but in IE9 it has them on the top left of the page. Any ideas on what I am missing? In IE9 and Chrome it is also missing the rounded edges of the buttons. The round edges only work with IE11.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("Wallpaper.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: #00ADEF;
}
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button {
  appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #941c2f;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #C1CFDA;
  color: black;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <a href="URL" class="button" target="_blank">URL</a>
  <a href="URL2" class="button" target="_blank" disabled>URL2</a>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think flexbox is supported in IE9 http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: for Ie9 you can use display:tabe/table-cell as alternative diplay behavior . justify content and align-items will not be avalaibke, but text-align and vertical-align might do an acceptable alternative.

Comment: So what would be the best way to get these 2 buttons in the middle of the page horizontally and vertically. I tried the display table, but it seemed to only center it vertically not horizontally.